# No subsetting of data.frame in shiny app when inputs are empty, how to do this without many if statements?

Tags: r, shiny

I am subsetting a dataframe in a shiny app based on various inputs the user can specify. If an input field is empty, no subsetting should be done. I can achieve this inside a reactive statement with

```
data_subset <- reactive({
  if (!is.null(input$input_a)) {data <- subset(data, a %in% input$input_a}
  # lots of similar if statements for inputs b, c, d ...
  data
})
```

where I have lots of these if statements checking if an input is NULL. But with more than 10 or 20 such statements one below the other, the code looks kind of messy and lengthy.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe req can help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to tweak this code to suit your needs. `input` is a list containing the different elements you are using to subset. You can extract those that you need in your reactive function and then use higher order function `Reduce` to come up with a logical vector to index your data.

```
# Setup example
input <- list(input_vs = NULL, input_am = 1, input_gear = 4) # Inputs coming from ui
data <- mtcars # Data


# In the reactive expression
inpt <- reactiveValuesToList(input)
indx <- inpt[grepl("input", names(inpt))] # Extract the inputs you want
names(indx) <- gsub("input_", "", names(indx)) # Remove the prefix to get the associated variable names

indx <- Filter(Negate(is.null), indx) # Remove the null ones

# Find indices
indx <- lapply(seq_along(indx), function(i) data[, names(indx)[i]] %in% indx[[i]])
indx <- Reduce(`&`, indx)

# Subset data
data[indx, ]
```

Comment: In shiny input is an R6 class, so single-bracket indexing won't work in `indx <- input[grepl("input", names(input))]`

Comment: there is a function `reactiveValuesToList` that solves that

Comment: Nice, thanks! Though it won't work if every input is NULL, because then indx is NULL and data[indx, ] is a zero-length data.frame

Answer (score 1):

I've just come up with a solution using a simple for loop. I defined a helper function to check if an input is empty and subset only if an input is not empty.

```
library(shiny)

data <- iris

# return TRUE if shiny input is empty, e.g. NULL, "", FALSE
is_input_empty <- function(ui_input) {
  if (is.null(ui_input)) return(TRUE)
  if (length(ui_input) != 1) return(FALSE)
  if (ui_input == "") return(TRUE)
  if (ui_input == FALSE) return(TRUE)
  return(FALSE)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  selectizeInput("Species", "Species", choices = levels(data$Species),
                 multiple = TRUE, selected = c("versicolor", "setosa")),
  plotOutput("plot_iris")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    data_subset <- reactive({
      input_vars <- "Species"

      # iterate over the inputs, if not NULL subset the data
      for (i in input_vars){
        if (!is_input_empty(input[[i]])) {data <- data[data[, i] %in% input[[i]], ]}
      }
      data
    })

    output$plot_iris <- renderPlot(plot(data_subset()$Sepal.Length, 
                                        data_subset()$Sepal.Width))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```